# I want to plot a very basic line chart with plotly

Tags: python, plotly, figure

I want to plot a very basic line chart with plotly

I have done (see below) this and I got: "*PlotlyRequestError: No message"

[fulltraceback](https://nb.anaconda.cloud/jupyterhub/user/56585ce6-2ede-48fb-b2a5-f70ac9b802fc/lab/workspaces/auto-c/tree/Untitled9.ipynb?)

Comment: Please post the full traceback

Comment: hi SiHa, the traceback is too long
below you just see a part of it...


OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
File /opt/conda/envs/anaconda-2022.05-py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:700, in HTTPConnectionPool.urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    699 if is_new_proxy_conn and http_tunnel_required:
--> 700     self._prepare_proxy(conn)
    702 # Make the request on the httplib connection object...

Comment: I ran it with my API key and the graph was created successfully. From the error message, I would guess that urllib3 may be the issue. I am using `urllib3: 1.26.13`.

Comment: i just ran it with your urllib: 1.26.13  but same thing

Comment: please post the full traceback *in the question*, you can use [edit] to do so

Comment: i created a link through jupyterlab
did you get it?